# Push DNS server instead of Router's IP on OpenWRT

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, cloudflare, google, openwrt

I have a router with OpenWRT installed.

In the section Network → Interfaces → WAN → Edit → Advanced Settings I have set up my custom DNS servers (Cloudflare and Google).

Now my routers continues to push his IP (192.168.0.1) to DHCP clients instead of the IP of the DNS Server (1.1.1.1, for example).

How can I change this?

Thank you all ;)

Comment: Check in the DHCP server configuration of the router.

Comment: OpenWRT uses dnsmasq as a local dns proxy and dhcp server. Don't worry, you're still using the cloudflare or google servers upstream, it's just passing the requests to the router first where it's providing some record caching to improve your network performance